# Keras custom Layer Gives Abnormal results

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I was trying to understand how Keras custom layers work. I am trying to create a multiplication layer that takes a scalar input and multiples it with the multiplicand. I generate some random data and want to learn the multiplicand. When I try with 10 numbers, it works fine. However, when I try with 20 numbers, the loss just explodes.

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras import initializers

class MultiplicationLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MultiplicationLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='multiplicand', 
                                  shape=(1,),
                                  initializer='glorot_uniform',
                                  trainable=True)
        self.built = True

    def call(self, x):
        return self.kernel*x

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

Using TensorFlow backend.

test the model 1 with 10 numbers

```
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model

# input is a single scalar
input = Input(shape=(1,))
multiply = MultiplicationLayer()(input)

model = Model(input, multiply)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')

import numpy as np
input_data = np.arange(10)
output_data = 2 * input_data

model.fit(input_data, output_data, epochs=10)
#print(model.layers[1].multiplicand.get_value())
print(model.layers[1].get_weights())
```

Epoch 1/10
10/10 [==============================] - 7s - loss: 257.6145
Epoch 2/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 47.6329
Epoch 3/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 8.8073
Epoch 4/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 1.6285
Epoch 5/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.3011
Epoch 6/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.0557
Epoch 7/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.0103
Epoch 8/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.0019
Epoch 9/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.5193e-04
Epoch 10/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 6.5076e-05

[array([ 1.99935019], dtype=float32)]

test the model 2 with 20 numbers

```
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model

# input is a single scalar
input = Input(shape=(1,))
multiply = MultiplicationLayer()(input)

model = Model(input, multiply)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')

import numpy as np
input_data = np.arange(20)
output_data = 2 * input_data

model.fit(input_data, output_data, epochs=10)
#print(model.layers[1].multiplicand.get_value())
print(model.layers[1].get_weights())
```

Epoch 1/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 278.2014
Epoch 2/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 601.1653
Epoch 3/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 1299.0583
Epoch 4/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 2807.1353
Epoch 5/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 6065.9375
Epoch 6/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 13107.8828
Epoch 7/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 28324.8320
Epoch 8/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 61207.1250
Epoch 9/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 132262.4375
Epoch 10/10
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 285805.9688

[array([-68.71629333], dtype=float32)]

Any insights why this might happen?

Comment: Sounds funny.... but you're not calling `super(....).build()`.... could that be the cause of a few weird behaviors?

Comment: @DanielMöller I think self.built = True is the same thing. I tried using super(...).build() and it gave the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using another optimizer, such as `Adam(lr=0.1)`. This unfortunately requires 100 epochs...., or by using a smaller learning rate in the SGD, such as `SGD(lr = 0.001)`.

```
from keras.optimizers import *

# input is a single scalar
inp = Input(shape=(1,))
multiply = MultiplicationLayer()(inp)

model = Model(inp, multiply)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.1), loss='mse')

import numpy as np
input_data = np.arange(20)
output_data = 2 * input_data

model.fit(input_data, output_data, epochs=100)
#print(model.layers[1].multiplicand.get_value())
print(model.layers[1].get_weights())
```

Testing further, I noticed that `SGD(lr = 0.001)` also works, while `SGD(lr = 0.01)` blows out.

What I suppose is:

If your learning rate is enough to make your update go past the point by a distance greater than it was before, the next step will get an even greater gradient, making you go past the point again by an even greater distance.

Example with only one number:

```
inputNumber = 20
x = currentMultiplicand = 1 
targetValue = 40
lr = 0.01 

#first step (x=1):
mse = (40-20x)² = 400 
gradient = -2*(40-20x)*20 = -800
update = - lr * gradient = 8
new x = 9

#second step (x=9):
mse = (40-20x)² = 19600 #(!!!!!)
gradient = -2*(40-20x)*20 = 5600
update = - lr * gradient = -56
new x = -47
   #you can see from here that this is not going to be contained anymore...
```

The same example, with a lower learning rate:

```
inputNumber = 20
x = currentMultiplicand = 1 
targetValue = 40
lr = 0.001 

#first step (x=1):
mse = (40-20x)² = 400 
gradient = -2*(40-20x)*20 = -800
update = - lr * gradient = 0.8
new x = 1.8

#second step (x=1.8):
mse = (40-20x)² = 16 #(now this is better)
gradient = -2*(40-20x)*20 = -160
update = - lr * gradient = 0.16 #(decreasing update sizes....)
new x = 1.96
   #you can see from here that this converging...
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation @Daniel Moller. It makes sense now!